# Get data-* attribute value from select option vue ionic

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a simple select option in ionic vue.

I want to access the selected `json object` of the state on change from the data-* attribute in vue js.

Is there any possible ways to get the select option `data-details` in `onSelectState` ?

Here is the vue file:

```
<ion-item class="ion-margin-top">
  <ion-label position="floating">State</ion-label>
  <ion-select name="state_id" v-on:ionChange="onSelectState($event)">
    <ion-select-option
      v-for="state in state_list"
      :key="state.id"
      :value="state.id"
      :data-details="state"
    >
      {{ state.text }}
    </ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

Here is where is want to access the data-attribute on change

```
    onSelectState(event) {
      console.log(event);
    },
```

OR is there any possible ways to pass the `state` inside `onSelectState` function to access the data.

I get the `value` inside `event.detail` how can I get the `data-details` data inside the event !

**Edit:**
I used following method to submit the form

```
async registerBuyer() {

  const formData = new FormData(this.$refs.register_form);
  const data = {};
  for (let [key, val] of formData.entries()) {
    Object.assign(data, { [key]: val });
  }

  ... // used axios to submit the data to api
},
```

Comment: Well if that is what you want, then why not pass the object itself in the value? :value=state, and remove the data-details? The state.id passed in the value is already contained in that object.

Comment: @LuísSilva If I do that, when I use `new FormData` to submit the form,  it shows state_id = `[object object]` and could not submit the form. I need the id to submit the form and the whole object to process other things in the page. (I have edited the question)

Comment: the $event object has the "name" of the target so you don't need to use data-details

Comment: @AaronSaunders How can i access the `name` here in my code?

Comment: it should be on the event.target object

Comment: Yes I can get the name, but how can I get the whole object of the selected option in that?